# Limit of the solution of viscosity problem associated to Conservation Laws

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If $u^{\epsilon}$ be a solution of approximating viscous problem:

$u^{\epsilon}_{t} + F(u^{\epsilon})_{x}-\epsilon u^{\epsilon}_{xx}=0$ in $\mathbb R$ X $(0,\infty)$

$u^{\epsilon} = g$ on $\mathbb R$ X {${t=0}$}

Then prove that: $u^{\epsilon} \to u$ a.e. as $\epsilon \to 0$ for some limit function $u$ .

Comment: Are there any additional hypotheses on $g$, or any boundary conditions?

Comment: No !!.. the equation is at page $605$ of Evans .. There he has put it in assumptions!! ... But the result is true that I know...couldn't prove it! .. One more thing... $u^{\epsilon}$ is a SMOOTH solution of the equation. SO I THINK : in particular, $g$ is also smooth!!